# Update glibc in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, glibc

I just wanted to make use of the Cygwin x server, but when trying to start a program I am told that glibc is too old. I have version 2.3.2 but would need version 2.3.6. Is there any easy way to update this? Cant find this package in the cygwin setup routine.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe cygwin even uses glibc, does i t?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I wanna execute a program on a remote host and then I get the error message that glibc is too old. So that is then not a problem of cygwin itself I guess. I would just need to update cygwin on the remote host.

Comment: Is the remote host running cygwin? or is it a Linux box? I'm guessing the latter, in which case you need to ask the sysadmins to update GCC.

Comment: So it sounds like this has nothing to do with cygwin. (And almost certainly nothing to do with GCC!)

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Cygwin update, it should by default update all packages that have changed, which should give you the latest C library. A lot of "shoulds", but I've never had any issues.

However, this sounds like an error from the client program, running on a remote host, not the X server (which is running under Cygwin). I'm not sure how a Cygwin program would even report this.

Please edit your question, showing the actual program that you're running, and the exact text of any error message -- copied from either the console window or a dialog box.

Comment: yes, you are right. See above, error message comes from program on remote machine